# Load sharedpreference value when Settings page is popped

Tags: dart, flutter-layout

I've been struggling for days trying to solve this problem. I expanded on the fluter udacity course to help create my own app and it's not going well. In the backdrop of my app I populate the screen with a list of items got from a json file in my project. The list containst a path to my asset folder where there are audio files to be played when a user taps on a listtile in a listview. When the app starts everything works fine but I added a settings page where the user can change the volume of the audio but its not working. In my settins page I have a slider whose value is saved in sharedpreferences like this;

```
 _saveSharedPreferences(double volume) async {
_prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
await _prefs.setDouble(VolumeLevelPrefKey, volume);
}
```

I call it whenever the slider value changes

```
  ListTile(
                leading: Icon(
                  Icons.volume_down_sharp,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
                trailing: Container(
                  width: 290.0,
                  child: Slider(
                    divisions: 10,
                    max: 100.0,
                    label: '${_volume.round()}',
                    activeColor: Colors.blue,
                    inactiveColor: Colors.red,
                    value: _volume,
                    onChanged: (double value) {
                      setState(() {
                        _volume = value;
                        _saveSharedPreferences(_volume);
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              )
```

I've managed to keep the slider value fixed even after app restarts buy reading the value in `inistate()`

```
 @override
 void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _readSharedPreferences();
  }

 _readSharedPreferences() async {
_prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
_prefs.reload();
_volume = _prefs.getDouble(VolumeLevelPrefKey);
setState(() {});
}
```

On first start the current volume value loads with no issues but when I navigate to the settings page and back the value remains unchanged.

I read my shared preference value in `inistate()` and call `setstate()` just to be sure but I don't think it's being called. I tried reading from `didChangeDependencies()` and `didUpDateWidgets()` too but none of them are called. I've also tried passing a `UniqueKey()` to my Listtile that populates the listview with audiofiles but it doesn't work.

One more thing I've was to call setState when the settings page is popped by the navigator in my backdrop.dart.

```
 onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Settings()))
                .then((value) {
              setState(() {
                // refresh state of the BackDrop
              });
            });
          },
```

and settings.dart

```
 leading: IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.pop(context, true);
      },
    ),
```

I populate my backdrop with this worldlist in my word_translation.dart file.

```
 /// Creates fresh list of [LIstTile] widgets, given a list of [Word]s.
void _createWordList() {
    final _audioCache = AudioCache();
    var newLists = <Widget>[];
    _readSharedPreferences();
    for (var word in widget.category.words) {
      newLists.add(
        Card(
          child: ListTile(
            leading: word.emoji == "" ? null : Image.asset(word.emoji),
            title: Text(word.english),
            subtitle: Text(
              word.akan,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16.0),
            ),
            trailing: Icon(
              Icons.play_arrow,
              size: 28.0,
            ),
            onTap: () {
              _audioCache.play(word.audio, volume: _volume);
            },
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
    setState(() {
      _wordList = newLists;
    });
  }
```

Is there anything else I can try?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by reading the preferences in the build method. I don't even know why I post here sometimes.